# Insufficient permission error while deleting files google drive

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am trying to delete all the files in my google drive.

```py
request = drive_service.files().list().execute()
for a in request["files"]:
    drive_service.files().delete(fileId=a["id"]).execute()
```

What I am getting:

*returns a insufficient permission error.*

What I want:

*Delete all the files and remove everything from shared with me and make it look like a fresh new drive.*

**EDIT:**

- [image: image 1]
- [image: image 2]

**EDIT 2:**

Is it possible to remove those files?

**EDIT 3**

Since the file are shared with me and I think cannot use `delete()` function with them because I am not the owner.
So how can I remove those files from my drive, any workarounds for error insufficient permission.

Comment: Scope I am using is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`

Comment: Please check this link hope your problem was resolved [Here link](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive/issues/342)

Comment: The provided scope has the highest priority in `Gdrive`, so on paper you should be able to delete any file inside your google drive account (except for Application data folder), if you have implemented everything properly.

Comment: I have added images that I can do on the "shared with me" on the google drive website but not on the api @Suman

Comment: @VasuDeo.s can you check the added edits for a clear understanding of the problem

Answer (score 0):

> insufficient permission

Means that the user you have currently authenticated with has not granted you the permission to do what you are trying to do.  or the user them selves doesnt have access to do what you are trying to do.

## scope

In order for your application to be able to delete files you need write access to the users drive account. When you authenticated your user you supplied a scope If you are following one of the [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) then you most likely used something like

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly

Scopes are used to define what access your application needs and to request of the user in order to run your application.  This scope would only give you read access to a users drive account.  What you need is full access.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Make sure to reauthenticate your application again. It should pop up again and ask you to grant it access.  Once you have run your application requesting the proper access this will work.

## User doesnt own the file

If the user themselves doesn't own the file they cant delete it.

Comment: I used and tried with all the scopes including the one in your answer

Comment: Did you authenticate your application?  Did it pop up and show you the consent screen again?

Comment: Yes everytime , I deleted the token file and reauthenticate it

Comment: it is the files that are **"shared with me"** which is that I cant remove from the drive

Comment: You cant delete a file thats been shared with you. You dont own the file.

Comment: Well how do I unshare it.. what I mean is I want that file to be gone from my **"shared with me"** directory. Which is possible to do using the google drive website. And you can see after deleting, it shows **Removed 1 file. 1 removed file is still accessible to collaborators**

Comment: Thats a different question you need to remove the permissions of the user to the file not delete the file.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56770999/1841839  That should tell you how to do it you will need to convert the calls to python.