# How to programmatically remove a file from "share with me" in Google drive

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

Doing the following command with the full drive scope

```
var request = service.Files.Delete(fileId);
```

results in

> insufficient permission error.

When trying to delete a file from google drive "Shared with me" folder.

How do you delete a file from "Shared with me" when the user that is logged in does not actually have access to delete a file they don't own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the user in question doesn't own the file. After a lot of digging I realised that what you want to do is to remove the permissions for the user on the file in question.

The first thing you need to do is run an [about.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get?apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22*%22%7D) on the current user:

```
return service.About.Get().Execute();
```

This will give you the permission id of that user

> "permissionId": "060305882255734372",

Once that is done you can then do a [permissions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/get) on the file for that user:

```
var response = service.Permissions.Get(fileId, permissionId).Execute();
```

Response

```
{
 "kind": "drive#permission",
 "id": "06030588225573437",
 "type": "user",
 "role": "writer"
}
```

Which will give you the permission id on the file for the user in question.

Then you can delete the permission on the file for the user using [permission.delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/delete)

```
var response = service.Permissions.Delete(fileId, permissionId).Execute();
```

Comment: It seems that it only works when the owner of the file has assigned me as an editor. If I am a viewer only, I keep getting 403 error "insufficient permissions" when I try permissions.get, permissions.list and permissions.delete on the files shared with me. Is this the case?

Comment: well i wouldn't expect delete to work if you have read only.

Comment: The permissions.list() and permissions.get() also do not work for viewer role users. Besides, even for permissions.delete() we are not deleting the file itself, only the permission of the file, i.e. resign the permission to view the file. In the native Google Drive UI it works - you can "remove" any file from the "Shared With Me" pseudo-folder even if you role is "viewer", effectively it means deleting the permission.