# User can upload but can't delete file on shared drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the REST API to create [1], list [2] and delete [3] files.

An user with content manager privileges can create a file to a shared drive.
This user can also list the drive contents.
However, when trying to delete the same file with:

```
DELETE /drive/v3/files/<fileid>?supportsAllDrives=true
```

a 403 Forbidden error is returned with a body like this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
 }
}
```

This can be reproduced with Google API Explorer.

Edit:

About get [4] returns

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?supportsAllDrives=true

{
 "user": {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  "displayName": "Jessy Hurley",
  "me": true,
  "permissionId": "03805955809493222960",
  "emailAddress": "jessyhurley@ondazultecnologia.com"
 }
}
```

Permissions get [5] returns

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1PWntiqRbg3ZhPdqkNBAv7_NpevGrHsO1/permissions/03805955809493222960?supportsAllDrives=true

{
 "kind": "drive#permission",
 "id": "03805955809493222960",
 "type": "user",
 "role": "fileOrganizer"
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create

[2] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

[3] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete

[4] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get

[5] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmticly remove a file from "share wtih me" in Google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56770881/how-to-programmticly-remove-a-file-from-share-wtih-me-in-google-drive)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I played with the permissions with no luck. I'm failing to see how removing a permission will allow the user to delete a file. I tried to remove the permission and got 403 "Cannot update or delete an inherited permission on a shared drive item."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [6] a content manager user can't permanently delete files.
So I change the call to move to trash using [7]:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1PWntiqRbg3ZhPdqkNBAv7_NpevGrHsO1?supportsAllDrives=true
{
  "trashed": true
}
```

[6] https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337554?hl=en

[7] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update